# Reaction Role with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I want to make my bot creating an embed and add some emoji that when you press, them give you a role. I also want to do that when the bot restart, I don't need to restart the embed too, you know.

If you don't really understand, please ask in the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can add reaction to a message:

```
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
```

And this is how you handle reaction roles:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == THE_ID_OF_YOUR_MESSAGE:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        if str(payload.emoji) == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=ROLE_NAME)
            await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.message_id == THE_ID_OF_YOUR_MESSAGE:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        if str(payload.emoji) == "":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=ROLE_NAME)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

This one works even after the bot was restarted.

Paste the role's name that you want to give on reaction instead of ROLE_NAME

Change THE_ID_OF_YOUR_MESSAGE to the id of the message that you reacted to with the bot before.

Comment: For the first script, I have to create the embed? Because it says embed=embed

Comment: Yes of course. It refers to an embed named as "embed" but if you name it something else, don't forget to change it to `embed=YOUR_EMBED_NAME`

Comment: I'll upload another response in a moment where I explain. It will be easier then in comments :D

Comment: If I want to put more emoji, how can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, but now by doing some tests I understand what I have to do. I only want to know how to add more emoji

Comment: You just paste in a bunch of that `await msg.add_reaction("")` and change the emoji.

Comment: One last thing, if I want to do more than one reaction role, for the embed command I just need to change the name after async def, but for the rest, do I have to change anything after async def? Because I'm afraid that being with the same name will overwrite the command and no longer work

Comment: You should leave `@bot.event` and `async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` as they are, and you need to make a change with the emoji and the role you want to give/remove

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the question in the comments of my other answer:

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx:commands.Context):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title",description="Description",color=discord.Colour.green())
    embed.add_field(name="Fieldname",value="Fieldvalue")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")
```

And after this you will have a message in the chatroom where you used the command. Then you want to copy the id of this message and then paste it to the place of THE_ID_OF_YOUR_MESSAGE

Or you could use global variable to get the id but I don't recommend that one for beginners.